# Brocade NetIron CER 2024C BGP config Issue

Tags: cisco-ios

I'm new to Brocade/NetIron but I thought the config was similar to Cisco until we tried to hook up a new transit provider. Routes don't seem to be loading correctly and we have an issue pinging our router on the Cogent issued IP that we have added onto the interface.

Can anyone see a problem with this config?

```
NetIron CER 2024C-4X#show run

Current configuration:
!
ver V5.6.0gT183
!
no spanning-tree
!

vlan 1 name DEFAULT-VLAN 
!
!
!
!
!
enable telnet password  .....
enable super-user-password  .....
telnet server
!
!
ip prefix-list VISPA-OUT seq 25 permit 1.2.3.0/24 
!
ip prefix-list ALL-PREFIXES seq 5 permit 0.0.0.0/0 le 32 
!
ip prefix-list DENY-ALL seq 5 deny 0.0.0.0/0 le 32 
!
!
!
!
!
ip router-id 1.2.3.1
!
!
!
!
!
interface management 1
 ip address 192.168.1.245/24
 enable
!
interface ethernet 2/1
 port-name *** Cogent ***
 enable
 ip address x.x.x.42/29
!
interface ethernet 2/4
 enable
 ip address 1.2.3.1/24
!
!
!
router bgp
 local-as 29129
 neighbor x.x.x.41 remote-as 174
 neighbor x.x.x.41 description Cogent

 address-family ipv4 unicast
 synchronization                                                  
 network 1.2.3.0/24
 redistribute connected
 neighbor x.x.x.41 route-map in COGENT-IN
 neighbor x.x.x.41 route-map out COGENT-OUT
 exit-address-family

 address-family ipv4 multicast
 exit-address-family

 address-family ipv6 unicast
 exit-address-family

 address-family ipv6 multicast
 exit-address-family

 address-family vpnv4 unicast
 exit-address-family

 address-family vpnv6 unicast
 exit-address-family

!
!                                                                 
!
route-map COGENT-IN permit 20
 match ip address prefix-list ALL-PREFIXES
 set local-preference 300 
!
route-map COGENT-OUT permit 10
 match ip address prefix-list VISPA-OUT
route-map COGENT-OUT deny 20
 match ip address prefix-list ALL-PREFIXES
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
end
```

BGP Sum :-

```
NetIron CER 2024C-4X#show run
NetIron CER 2024C-4X#show ip bgp sum
  BGP4 Summary 
  Router ID: 1.2.3.1   Local AS Number: 123
  Confederation Identifier: not configured
  Confederation Peers: 
  Maximum Number of IP ECMP Paths Supported for Load Sharing: 1
  Number of Neighbors Configured: 1, UP: 1
  Number of Routes Installed: 2, Uses 172 bytes
  Number of Routes Advertising to All Neighbors: 1 (1 entries), Uses 48 bytes
  Number of Attribute Entries Installed: 2, Uses 180 bytes
  Neighbor Address  AS#         State   Time          Rt:Accepted Filtered Sent     ToSend
  x.x.x.41      174         ESTAB   0h 7m 6s      0           0        1        0
```

I can ping Cogent's IP, x.x.x.41 fine.

I can't ping my router from the outside world. Cogent also can't ping me - x.x.x.42.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't find anything related to programming in your question. It looks like it's off-topic here.

Comment: It's not a programming question, it's an operating system BGP question.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a default route.

ip route 0.0.0.0/0 x.x.x.x

where x.x.x.x is your cogent gateway.